# Printing buttons acording to values on the database

Tags: php

I have 2 buttons, one is to accept, the other one is to refuse and I have a field on the database called "status".
If the value of that field is "**Refused**" it prints both buttons but the refuse button is disabled, in order to not let the user refuse again, only letting the user accept and if the value is "**Accepted**" it prints both buttons but the accept one is disabled.
I wanted to know if my code could be improved and if there was a most efficient way to do this than the way that I did it (which I think it's a poor solution and that's why I'm posting this question).
The code:

```
<?php
      if ($status == "Accepted") {
         echo "<button disabled style='width:130px;cursor:not-allowed;' class='btn btn-success' name='accept' type='submit'><b>Accept</b></button>";
         echo "<button style='width:130px; margin-left: 10px;' class='btn btn-danger' name='refuse' type='submit'><b>Refuse</b></button>";
      } else if ($status == "Refused") {
         echo "<button disabled style='width:130px;cursor:not-allowed; margin-left: 10px;' class='btn btn-danger' name='refuse' type='submit'><b>Refuse</b></button>";
         echo "<button style='width:130px; margin-left: 10px' class='btn btn-success' name='accept' type='submit'><b>Accept</b></button>";
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a coding-style question. There are no "correct" answers. Just opinions.

However, if you were to rewrite this code in a shorter way, you would probably make it less readable to other developers. Since the point of your question is to improve the code, and I assume you mean "make this more readable", then I think you're best off leaving it alone.

The only problem I would highlight is that you've changed the order in which the buttons are displayed. If you display two buttons on a page, then the next time you view that page, the same two buttons should be in the same order on that page. Otherwise people may click the wrong one by mistake.

Comment: I realized it now and I fixed the order.
I wasn't really talking about making it more readable, I was talking about rewriting it in a shorter/more efficient way, for example, insthead of printing the same two buttons twice maybe I could make it so I just had to write them once and the program would do exactly same while saving some lines of code.

Comment: my point here is that yes, you could possibly save a few bytes by rewriting slightly shorter, but at the expense of legibility.

writing clever code is fun at the time, but when you have to have to decipher it in a few years to fix a bug, it's not so fun.

at the speed that computers run, you're not going to notice any increase in speed by rewriting this in any way at all.

if you insist on being clever, then you could use ternary operators to shorten the logic, or do some clever array manipulation, but I highly recommend that you do not do that.